# clean xml tweet from unknown characters with action script

Tags: xml, regex, actionscript-3, twitter

I'm reading tweets via XML format depending on hashtags, but I'm encountering some strange characters in tweets which are causing me troubles.  For example:

I managed to fix it with php with this code I found online:

```
$thetweet = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x10\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x19\x7F]'.
             '|[\x00-\x7F][\x80-\xBF]+'.
             '|([\xC0\xC1]|[\xF0-\xFF])[\x80-\xBF]*'.
             '|[\xC2-\xDF]((?![\x80-\xBF])|[\x80-\xBF]{2,})'.
             '|[\xE0-\xEF](([\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]))|(?![\x80-\xBF]{2})|[\x80-\xBF]{3,})/S',
             '?', $thetweet );
```

However, this regular expression does not work in ActionScript 3.
Can anyone help applying this code in ActionScript?  It's not accepting this regex.

Answer (score 0):

According to the very strange documentation, you have to double escape hex escape sequence.

I don't know, the docs are bad . But you could try

raw:

```
[\\x00-\\x08\\x10\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x19\\x7F]|[\\x00-\\x7F][\\x80-\\xBF]+|([\\xC0\\xC1]|[\\xF0-\\xFF])[\\x80-\\xBF]*|[\\xC2-\\xDF]((?![\\x80-\\xBF])|[\\x80-\\xBF]{2,})|[\\xE0-\\xEF](([\\x80-\\xBF](?![\\x80-\\xBF]))|(?![\\x80-\\xBF]{2})|[\\x80-\\xBF]{3,})/S
```

delimited:

```
/[\\x00-\\x08\\x10\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x19\\x7F]|[\\x00-\\x7F][\\x80-\\xBF]+|([\\xC0\\xC1]|[\\xF0-\\xFF])[\\x80-\\xBF]*|[\\xC2-\\xDF]((?![\\x80-\\xBF])|[\\x80-\\xBF]{2,})|[\\xE0-\\xEF](([\\x80-\\xBF](?![\\x80-\\xBF]))|(?![\\x80-\\xBF]{2})|[\\x80-\\xBF]{3,})\/S/
```

Comment: That didn't work... i guess the regular expression is too long, flash is not able to handle it for some reason...

Comment: Try a simple text to see if it matches a single hex construct - `/[\\x20]/` a space in this case. This at least tells you if that is the problem. That particular regex can be factored down a little anyway.

Comment: sighs, im getting frustrated with flash.
I created a PHP portal that takes the xml, cleans it, then return a new xml.

I appreciate your help tho. thanks a bunch.

Comment: Adobe is some strange company. Good luck! Edit, btw I don't think there is a text limit on regex's. I've seen url regex's close to 30k in length.

Comment: Thanks. now i have another problem.

Arabic text words are being misplaces , change order in the sentence. do you happen to know a solution for that ? :( its my first project in flash and im really hating it...